# How to check if complex number is in field?

Tags: ring-theory, complex-numbers, field-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working through [Elliptic Tales](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691151199/elliptic-tales) for self study.

The objective is to form an algebraic closure for the field $F_2$. (Elements are $0$, $1$ and operations are mod 2).

We start by defining the root of $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$ as $a$.

We then get the set $F_4$ which consists of 4 elements: $0$, $1$, $a$, $1 + a$.

The book says we can check that $F_4$ is a field if we use common algebra to add and multiply.

For example: $a + a = 0$ according to the book. But this is not obvious to me. Why would the addition of $a$ with itself result in $0$?

Comment: $a+a=2\cdot a=0\cdot a=0$.

Comment: I see, so the modulo is still in effect?

Comment: Yes, since $2=1+1$.

Comment: Also, $a$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ which is irreducible in $F_2[x]$, but $a$ is not a complex number.

Comment: @quasi, when I plug the above equation into an online solver I get the roots are $-\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, which seem like complex numbers?

Comment: Generally online solvers only solve equations over the complex numbers, not over finite fields.